# How can i enlarge a Jbutton from the center when it's hover?

Tags: java, windowbuilder

How can i enlarge a Jbutton from the center when it's hover? I use the method setSize(), but the button enlarges to the right and down. I'd like to make it enlarge to all the directions. The JButton is in a JPanel with a flowLayout.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a transparant border for your button, and when hovering over it, set the border-size to 0.

This is your initial code for the button border:

```
JButton btn = ...;
Color borderColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0,); //Transparant border
btn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(borderColor, 4));
```

When hover, you should set the border to this:

```
btn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(borderColor, 0));
```

That should be a quick workaround.

Comment: Very smart solution, really simple. Tanks

Comment: Could you mark my answer as the correct one? Here is how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer